# "GradientFill was not declared in this scope" error when including windows.h and wingdi.h

Tags: c++, winapi, codeblocks

Here is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wingdi.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message) //handling the message; all cases should be in logical order
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc;
            GRADIENT_RECT rc;
            TRIVERTEX vertex[2] ;
            //vertex settings...

            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            GradientFill(hdc, vertex, 2, &rc, 1, GRADIENT_FILL_RECT_V);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the message from title, and when I switch wingdi.h and windows.h I get load of errors from wingdi.h file.
I use codeblocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [GradientFill](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144957.aspx) tells you, which header declares a symbol and which header to include:

> Header: WinGdi.h (include Windows.h)

While `GradientFill` is declared in *WinGdi.h* you should `#include <Windows.h>` only.

---

*Note:* In case this doesn't solve your issues, you might want to consider picking another IDE. Code::Blocks is known to be brittle, with lots of issues, and a soft spot for wrong defaults (e.g. ANSI/Codepage character encoding vs. Unicode). [Visual Studio Community 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) is a full featured IDE that can be used free of charge.

Comment: Yes, I tried that in the beginning and it did not solve the issue. I will take a look at VSC2015, thank you for the suggestion! I will leave this open in case anybody solves it in CodeBlocks.

Comment: Also put `#define WINVER 0x0501` before the includes, and you need the equivalent of `Msimg32.lib`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: `GradientFill` is available in Windows 2000 already, so that would be `0x0500`.

Comment: Yes it should be at least `0x0500` for this API. CodeBlock doesn't define `WINVER` at all. Minimum target XP might be more practical, or better yet Vista.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: The conditional for `GradientFill` in *WinGdi.h* is `WINVER >= 0x0400`. In case `WINVER` is not already defined, *WinGdi.h* defaults to settings it to `0x0500`. Even if Code::Blocks doesn't automatically set `WINVER`, `GradientFill` is available.

Comment: `GradientFill` looks for `WINVER >= 0x0410` according to MinGW header files. CodeBlocks compilation fails assuming it uses those header files. But OP has not explained what he is using with CodeBlock.

Comment: @DanielMaczak, For Windows only C++ development, you need not to look beyond Visual Studio. Now!

Comment: @Ajay well I was hoping to stay out of it for as long as possible because I am not very keen of their extensive usage of resource files and creating windows in simple graphic editor, I want to write everything myself in pure c++ so that I learn how it works during the process.

Comment: @DanielMaczak: Some items **must** be resources (e.g. the application icon); you cannot do this using code, as it must be available without running any code (e.g. to show it in a file manager). Other than that, feel free to not use resources in Visual Studio. Creating a regular Win32 GUI application leaves out much of the resources, with the exception of a menu and about dialog resource. Both can be deleted easily, if that is worrying you. Or just go ahead and create an empty Win32 project.

Comment: @DanielMaczak, VS allows you to debug assembly and it allow you to build rich XAML based mobile applications. Most PE images would have some kind of resource. You can create full blown GUI application without using resource editors/files, if you are capable of!

Comment: @IInspectable I pasted all my project data into VS, had to redefine like 50 char values and now it works! Thank you a lot for help on my questions, you're a real life saver.